# Why will the Paging not work on this RadGrid

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have a Telerik RadGrid setup with this

```
<div id="RadGird" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" 
                    OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand"
                    RenderMode="Lightweight"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    AllowSorting="True"
                    AllowPaging="true"
                    AllowCustomPaging ="true"
                     OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" GroupPanelPosition="Top" PageSize="50">
                     <ClientSettings>
                             <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="true" FrozenColumnsCount="2"></Scrolling>
                     </ClientSettings>
                    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" DataKeyNames="ID"
                        Font-Size="Small" Name="MasterView" TableLayout="Fixed">
                        <CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="true" ShowRefreshButton="False" />
                        <CommandItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CommandName="AddNewInmate" CausesValidation="false" Visible='<%# !RadGrid1.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted %>'><img style="border:0px" alt="" src="images/AddRecord.png" /> Add new Inmate</asp:LinkButton>
                        </CommandItemTemplate>
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false" UniqueName="Edit">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="EditRecord" runat="server" CommandName="EditInmate" CausesValidation="false" Visible='<%# !RadGrid1.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted %>'><img style="border:0px" alt="" src="images/icon_edit.gif" /></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn Display="false" DataField="ID" UniqueName="ID" DataType="System.String"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn AllowFiltering="False" DataField="RecDate" DataType="System.DateTime" Display="True" HeaderText="Received Date"    UniqueName="ReceivedDate" DataFormatString="{0:M/d/yyyy}" Visible="True"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="false" DataField="InNumber" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="InNumber" Display="true" HeaderText="InNumber"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="false" DataField="FCNumber" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="FCNumber" Display="true" HeaderText="SID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="false" DataField="JackNumber" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="JackNumber" Display="true" HeaderText="Jack Number"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="false" DataField="Comments" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="Comments" Display="true" HeaderText="Comments"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="false" DataField="Employee" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="AddedBy" Display="true" HeaderText="Added By"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="false" DataField="Status" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="Status" Display="true" HeaderText="Status"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="false" DataField="Type" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="Type" Display="true" HeaderText="Type"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </MasterTableView>
                    <ClientSettings ReorderColumnsOnClient="true" AllowColumnsReorder="true" ColumnsReorderMethod="Reorder">
            <Virtualization EnableVirtualization="true" InitiallyCachedItemsCount="2000"
                LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" ItemsPerView="50"/>
            <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true" ScrollHeight="500px" />
            <Resizing AllowColumnResize="true" />
        </ClientSettings>
        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced"></PagerStyle>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
            </div>
```

Everything loads and shows the data but I cannot see any paging controls I get the first 50 records but no page controls.

What an I missing

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add "**AlwaysVisible=true**" in PageStyle tag. It may be help for this issue.